# Multiple Seeds Content Based filtering Recommender System

Tags: data-mining, dataset, recommender-system

I want to create a content based filtering recommender system which has multiple seeds. All that I have read about is having an initial seed from which the recommendations should be similar to. This is particularly helpful in situations where you want to create movie recommendations that should be interesting to a group of people. So I need a `query seed` which is a single row of movie features to feed to the recommender. So how do I create a `query seed` based from multiple rows of movie features?

Comment: You just explained the context, but what is the question?